# How do You simulate Requests using Already placed Json Data with python/flask

Tags: python, python-requests

New to this, How do you simulate a HTTP Request with data which is already json and send it thru requests in python. I am trying to do it and its telling me, JSON Not serializable.

these are the lines of code which I am using

```
@app.route('/api/create-virtual-account',methods=['POST'])
@jwt_required()
def create_virtual_account():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    _json = request.json
    _account_name = _json['account_name']
    _email = current_user
    _bvn = _json['bvn']
    _tx_ref = 'VAL12'
    _phonenumber = _json['phonenumber']
    _firstname = _json['firstname']
    _lastname = _json['lastname']
    _narration = _json['narration']

    url = 'URL HERE'

    data = {'account_name':_account_name,'email':_email,'bvn':_bvn,'phonenumber':_phonenumber,'firstname':_firstname,'lastname':_lastname,'narration':_narration}
    res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data),headers={'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization':'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X'})
    
    return jsonify({'result':res.content}),200
```

I know there is something i am missing, only i am not sure what it is. I am fairly new to this, so I need guidance

This is the Error i am getting

```
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2022-10-28 20:43:12,650] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/create-virtual-account [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\emi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\emi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask_jwt_extended\view_decorators.py", line 154, in decorator
    return current_app.ensure_sync(fn)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\flask_rest_api_tut\****\main.py", line 177, in create_virtual_account
    return jsonify({'result':res.content}),200
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 342, in jsonify
    return current_app.json.response(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 309, in response
    f"{self.dumps(obj, **dump_args)}\n", mimetype=mimetype
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 230, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\json\provider.py", line 122, in _default
    raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2022 20:43:12] "POST /api/create-virtual-account HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Could you return `return jsonify({'result':res.json()}),200` instead of `res.content` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `res.content` use `res.json()`. `.json()` method will parse the Json response to Python objects so you can use `jsonify()` method without error:

```py
...

return jsonify({'result':res.json()}),200
```